# Class not dynamically changing with variable in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an icon inside a div, which has two classes bound to it using vue, everything works initially but on click the class 'linked' does not toggle on or off even though the variable h (which i have defined in data) changes from true to false or vice versa. What's going on?

```
        <div v-for="(i, ind) in icons_row1" :key="ind" xs4 md2>
            <button @click="h = !h" :title="titles[ind]"><i :class="[{'linked' : h}, i]" class="ficon" ></i></button>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic class you could try something like this:

```
  <div v-bind:class="[ somethingTrue ? 'styleA' : 'styleB' ]">Some text</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ku9brr33/

---

I have further updated the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ku9brr33/1/

Firstly you are using a  tag inside of a button, this I tag is by default 'inline' with no content, this means that your I tag will appear invisible... try adding some text in it.

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
     <button @click="somethingTrue = !somethingTrue" :title="btnTitle"> 
      click me  <i v-bind:class="[ somethingTrue ? 'styleA' : 'styleB' ]">Some text</i>
     </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The title attribute is what it shows when you hover over the button (see my example) not the text that gets displayed to the end user.

As you never provided any CSS in your original question its unclear as to what else you are really trying to do here.

Comment: It's not working, this is what i have  <button @click="h = !h" :title="titles[ind]"><i v-bind:class="[ h ? 'non' : 'linked']"></i></button>, the value of h changes but the class is not toggled

Comment: @kumail I have made updates and working example for you.